# PHP7 register_tick_function / declare affects only file it is declared in?

Tags: php, php-7

PHP7 register_tick_function / declare affects only the file it is declared in?
I used to profile in php 5.6< using register_tick_function/declare("ticks"),
but inside PHP7 I always get ticks only for the lines I explicitly mentioned declare construction file in, which doesn't allow me to profile the whole application as php5.6 and lower allowed me.

I tried to tamper with op_cache but didn't help to any avail.

inspiration: 
https://kpayne.me/2013/12/24/write-your-own-code-profiler-in-php/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the implementation of `declare` was a little buggy before PHP 7.0. The declare statement is only supposed to affect the file it is in, and therefore you must add `declare(ticks=1)` on each file. The existing usage was buggy and was "fixed" in PHP 7.0.

After some research, it looks like there's a comment on this in the [`register_tick_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php#121204) documentation

Comment: thank you very much :) stackoverflow is awesome. Although for me rather undesirable behaviour, it describes problem very well

Comment: I would recommend using XDebug anyway if possible. Much more functionality especially when you use a decent IDE to allow frame by frame debugging.

Comment: it is probably not best practice but i wanted to have ability to debug  this on UAT environment as well, where i dont have access to xdebug debugger or profiler but code is condition by different execution path by environment

Comment: How do I send you a beer?

Comment: Haha. I'm happy I helped you out!